# Python Simple json post

Tags: python, json, http, post, python-requests

Im trying to make a simple post request to "kahoot.it/#/"  , every time i make a request i get http 405 msg. 
Any ideas? , i also tried to use mechanize but its seems like not supporting JSON forms (br.select_form() )

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser
import json
import requests


authparams = json.JSONEncoder().encode({'gameId': '981103'})
r = requests.post("https://kahoot.it/", data=json.dumps(authparams),headers={'content-type':'application/json'})
print r
```

Comment: The 405 (method not allowed) seems pretty self explanatory. Is there an API document or similar that tells you to post to that specific URL?

Comment: @TomDalton kahoot dont own api , there is 2 fields i have to fill in order to move the next url : "https://kahoot.it/#/instructions"
both are json fields .

Comment: When I go to that page in my browser, I get a form with a "game PIN" text entry field, and a submit button. It's completely unclear how that (and HTML form) relates to your question of posting json data to that URL. You'll need to provide more details.

Comment: @TomDalton well, i tried to use html form filling with python (mechenize) its seems like this form not recognized .
for exemple i tryed to print all forms in this page by:
for form in br.forms():
    print forms

i didnt recived any forms from that page , thats why i think the form written in java script .

Comment: I don't think that *guessing* what the form/page is doing is going to help you. Use your browsers developer tools to work out what the page is doing, and then try to recreate that.